# not able to install ia32-libs on ubuntu 16.04(32bit)

Tags: software-installation, 32-bit

I am a very new Ubuntu user and want to install `ia32-libs` on ubuntu
 16.04(32bit).   I used `ia32-libs-multiarch_20090808ubuntu35_i386.deb` file to install but it is not installing.Showing following error.

```
root@n:/home/malik/Downloads# dpkg -i ia32-libs_20090808ubuntu35_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 202040 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ia32-libs_20090808ubuntu35_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ia32-libs:amd64 (20090808ubuntu35) over (20090808ubuntu35) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ia32-libs:amd64:
ia32-libs:amd64 depends on ia32-libs-multiarch; however:
Package ia32-libs-multiarch is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ia32-libs:amd64 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
ia32-libs:amd64
root@n:/home/malik/Downloads#
```

Comment: All suggestions are appreciated.....

Comment: `ia32-libs` has been deprecated for some time I think - multiarch should have made it obsolete. What is the **actual** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I assume you're trying to install a program that depends on `ia32-libs` directly or indirectly. If you tell us what exactly you're trying to achieve, we can probably find a better solution. You're also on a 32-bit installation so there should actually be no need for `ia32-libs`.

Comment: Same issue has been already handled in the link below. check it https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2025560

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 6 years.